# apple mach-o linker error while working with admob

Tags: ios

I have created a test project to test admob and leaarn how to use it but when I build my project I get 11 apple mach-o linker errors when I try to add admob into my project(Xcode 4.3.3)

The h file is oke and here is M file(codes are taken from admob knowlage base)

```
#import "chViewController.h"

#define MY_BANNER_UNIT_ID @"my id is written in here"

@interface chViewController ()

@end

@implementation chViewController

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Create a view of the standard size at the top of the screen.
    // Available AdSize constants are explained in GADAdSize.h.
    bannerView_ = [[GADBannerView alloc] initWithAdSize:kGADAdSizeBanner];

    // Specify the ad's "unit identifier." This is your AdMob Publisher ID.
    bannerView_.adUnitID = MY_BANNER_UNIT_ID;

    // Let the runtime know which UIViewController to restore after taking
    // the user wherever the ad goes and add it to the view hierarchy.
    bannerView_.rootViewController = self;
    [self.view addSubview:bannerView_];

    // Initiate a generic request to load it with an ad.
    [bannerView_ loadRequest:[GADRequest request]];
}


- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [super viewDidUnload];
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
}
```

Errors

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_SCNetworkReachabilityCreateWithName", referenced from:
      -[GADNetworkChecker startNetworkChecking] in libGoogleAdMobAds.a(GADNetworkChecker.o)
  "_SCNetworkReachabilityScheduleWithRunLoop", referenced from:
      -[GADNetworkChecker startNetworkChecking] in libGoogleAdMobAds.a(GADNetworkChecker.o)
  "_SCNetworkReachabilitySetCallback", referenced from:
      -[GADNetworkChecker startNetworkChecking] in libGoogleAdMobAds.a(GADNetworkChecker.o)
  "_SCNetworkReachabilityUnscheduleFromRunLoop", referenced from:
      -[GADNetworkChecker stopNetworkChecking] in libGoogleAdMobAds.a(GADNetworkChecker.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_ASIdentifierManager", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in libGoogleAdMobAds.a(GADIdentifierUtilities.o)
  "_AudioServicesPlaySystemSound", referenced from:
      -[GADWebViewDelegate webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationType:] in libGoogleAdMobAds.a(GADWebViewDelegate.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_SKStoreProductViewController", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in libGoogleAdMobAds.a(GADOpener.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_MFMailComposeViewController", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in libGoogleAdMobAds.a(GADOpener.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_MFMessageComposeViewController", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in libGoogleAdMobAds.a(GADOpener.o)
  "_SKStoreProductParameterITunesItemIdentifier", referenced from:
      -[GADOpener openInAppStore:fallbackURLString:] in libGoogleAdMobAds.a(GADOpener.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I have added lib.googleadmobAds to my folder and linked binary with libraries(when I remove it I receive same errors but 4 of them not 11)

I read lots of stackoveflow posts about it and some of you saying that I need also need to ad adsupport.framework but I cant find it I dont see it in the link binaries with libraries list.

None of these solutions on net is working I am stuck.

What is wrong with it I am not receiving any erros about my h or m files so why mach-o linker errors can somebody help me please ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need to link against the frameworks that AdMob requires.

Go to your target settings, then in Build Phases, then in Link  Binary with Libraries and add the following frameworks (you may need additional ones, these are juste based on the errors I see):

```
MessageUI.framework
StoreKit.framework
SystemConfiguration.framework
```

Comment: I add them all but there are still 4 errors also why admob documents dont say anything about these frameworks

Comment: It seems that I forgot AdSupport.framework and maybe AudioToolBox.framework. A good approach is to take the undefined classes (for example ASIdentifierManager) and search in Google in which framework they are located.

Comment: As of today, I also needed (in addition to AdSupport.framework) the following frameworks: EventKitUI.framework, EventKit.framework, and CoreTelephony.framework.

Answer (score 7):

These are the frameworks that I need to add to get thing going:

```
AdSupport.framework
AudioToolbox.framework
MessageUI.framework
SystemConfiguration.framework
StoreKit.framework
```

I already had:

```
UIKit.framework
Foundation.framework
CoreGraphics.framework
libGoogleAdMobAds.a
```

Good Documentation is:
https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need to link against the `SystemConfiguration` framework.

This [Apple Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#recipes/xcode_help-structure_navigator/articles/adding_a_framework.html) should help you configure Xcode to do that.

Comment: I linked system configuration.frame work and 4 errors are gone but still 7 errors they are all same why ???