# linking ObjC for iOS Simulator, but object file was compiled for MacOSX - Xcode 5 Preview

Tags: ios7, linker, xcode5

I have just switch to Xcode 5 Preview, getting lots of warning for one of existing project.

```
ld: warning: linking ObjC for iOS Simulator, but object file (/Projects/iOs/WWS/SVN/iOS/WWS/WWS/ExtFrameworks/GoogleAdMobAdsSdkiOS/libGoogleAdMobAds.a(GADSearchRequestPrivate.o)) was compiled for MacOSX
ld: warning: linking ObjC for iOS Simulator, but object file (/Projects/iOs/WWS/SVN/iOS/WWS/WWS/ExtFrameworks/GoogleAdMobAdsSdkiOS/libGoogleAdMobAds.a(GADCachedFile.o)) was compiled for MacOSX
ld: warning: linking ObjC for iOS Simulator, but object file (/Projects/iOs/WWS/SVN/iOS/WWS/WWS/ExtFrameworks/GoogleAdMobAdsSdkiOS/libGoogleAdMobAds.a(GADNetworkChecker.o)) was compiled for MacOSX
ld: warning: linking ObjC for iOS Simulator, but object file (/Projects/iOs/WWS/SVN/iOS/WWS/WWS/ExtFrameworks/GoogleAdMobAdsSdkiOS/libGoogleAdMobAds.a(GADTiming.o)) was compiled for MacOSX
ld: warning: linking ObjC for iOS Simulator, but object file (/Projects/iOs/WWS/SVN/iOS/WWS/WWS/ExtFrameworks/GoogleAdMobAdsSdkiOS/libGoogleAdMobAds.a(GADTimingManager.o)) was compiled for MacOSX
ld: warning: linking ObjC for iOS Simulator, but object file (/Projects/iOs/WWS/SVN/iOS/WWS/WWS/ExtFrameworks/GoogleAdMobAdsSdkiOS/libGoogleAdMobAds.a(GADRequestError.o)) was compiled for MacOSX
```

Comment: I don't see how that worked in Xcode 4.  Linking object files for OSX and iOS would never have worked.

Comment: Maybe these two SO questions can help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12403630/apple-mach-o-linker-error-armv7s-libgoogleadmobads-a http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14484442/apple-mach-o-linker-error-while-working-with-admob